# On the Air programming for Contiki

Tags: contiki

I'm new Sky Motes on contiki and i'm trying to reprogram the nodes at run time. I've tried the Deluge and it's example in test-deluge.c which is found under examples/sky/test-deluge.c but i don't know what to do after uploading the code to node. So any Help Please ! My main target to reprogram the node on the Air

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Deluge only distributes the data to the nodes. You still need to link the file on the node. This is done by passing a coffee-file-descriptor to `elfloader_load()`.

You can find example code in [shell-exec.c](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/apps/shell/shell-exec.c). There is an [sky-shell-exec example](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/tree/master/examples/sky-shell-exec) using the shell to load a file as well as a [regression-test (07-elfloader)](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/tree/master/regression-tests/07-elfloader) that verifies that the sky-shell-exec example works.